# How to disable Lightning button after click

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:attribute name="Likedisable" type="Boolean" default="true" />

 <a onclick="{!c.disable}">

<lightning:button  aura:id="button1" label="button1" value="up" class="thumb" disabled="{!v.Likedisable}">
        <img src="{!$Resource.thumbs + '/like.png'}" width="20" height="20" /> 
    </lightning:button> 
</a>


uprate : function(component, event, helper) {
component.set("v.Likedisable",false);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `event.getSource().set("v.disabled", true);`

Answer (score 0):

Please make the following update in your code.

1. Make `Likedisable` default value to `false`.
2. Make `Component.set("v.Likedisable",true)` in update function.

Comment: Seems like Initially, he is trying  to display the button after click he is trying to disable the button

Comment: @AnnappaPH Initially the default value of Likedisable button is true.